# How to set items to be one column and the column stretch horizontal in GridLayout?

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-gridlayout, recyclerview-layout

I wish to be below.

[image]

But now, it look like below.

[image]

I know why it is.

Below is my code.

```
this.mFilterCategoryListAdapter = new FilterCategoryListAdapter(getContext());
this.mFilterCategoryListAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
this.binding.recyclerViewCategories.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3));
this.binding.recyclerViewCategories.setAdapter(this.mFilterCategoryListAdapter);

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewCategories"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

I set 3 with spanCount in GrayLayout Constructor like this.

```
setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3));
```

But this can't make that I wish.
So I think spanCount set '1' and stretch width 100%.
But I don't know this way..

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I think https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout may help you

Comment: @PhanVanLinh You are right! I fixed it. Thank u :)